# Web Scraping content from multiple pages without visiting each through a webdriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm fairly new to web scraping, but I've managed to create my program which allows me to scrape certain data (dynamic content) by accessing the page with the selenium web driver.

Specifically, I am scraping data from a FAQ page (number of views per post) but on this site, there is no way to check the number of comments per post without having to click on each post and checking it manually. At the moment, I've coded so that the web driver can simply detect the number of views from each post as it scans down page 1 of the general posting page and continues to do so for the proceeding pages.

As far as I know, the source code in the general posting page does not display anything to do with the number of comments and I figured if I were to access every single post, the processing time would increase dramatically. Is there any way I could acquire the number of comments without having my web driver enter every single post?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the HTML structure for the page?

Comment: please include your code, the relevant html using the snippet tool via [edit] and ideally the url.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the page architecture.

You can check if this site uses an API to make requests to the database so you can make some posts and use the API to get the data.

Otherwise, if you can not benefit from it, you can try to use python with aiohttp to make the brute scrape avoiding the connection/IO bound with asynchronous Tasks.

Take a look:

1. [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)
2. [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
3. [asyncronous scrape sample](https://medium.com/@santhoshhari/efficient-web-scraping-with-pythons-asynchronous-programming-6b9e730f1ff7)